# modifying elements of tensor at given indices and conditions

Tags: python, pytorch

Say I have a tensor:

```
x = torch.tensor([[1,   0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
[0, 1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
[0, 0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0],
[1, 0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0],
[0, 0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  0],
[0, 0,  1,  0,  0,  1,  0],
[0, 0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  1],
[0, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
[0, 0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0],
[1, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]])
```

and column indices:

```
col_inds = torch.tensor([3,4,5])
```

the rows that contain ones in these cols are

```
row_inds = torch.where(x[:,col_inds]==1)[0]
```

I want to convert all ones to zeros in `x` at `row_inds` except if their column index exists in the `col_inds`. This change is done in sequence, so that if there are more than one "ones" in a row in columns that exist in col_inds, then only the first "one" is kept, and the rest become zero. see for example, x[4,5] is zero in the output because a "one" was first discovered in x[4,4]. Eventually, there is only one "one" in the `row_inds`.
So the output would be:

```
([[1,   0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
[0, 1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
[0, 0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0],
[**0**, 0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0],
[0, 0,  0,  0,  1,  **0**,  0],
[0, 0,  **0**,  0,  0,  1,  0],
[0, 0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  **0**],
[0, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
[0, 0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0],
[1, 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]])
```

I am able to do this if only one column is in question,

```
for rr in row_inds: 
    x[rr] = 0 
    x[rr,col_ind] = 1
```

but my technique is not working on multiple columns.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is `cols` in your example? Is it a typo for `col_inds`?